# How does Stack Overflow mirror what you're typing?

Tags: text, editor, preview

Right now while I'm typing this there's the preview down below the editor. I would like to do something similar. How does Stack Overflow do this?

Comment: I'm confused. Should this belong to meta or not?

Comment: ... and thats why it sucks on iPhone :-)

Comment: I wouldn't think so. It's just as valid as any other question, he just happens to use StackOverflow as an example of implementation. If he had used any other site it wouldn't be migrated.

Comment: @erelender  _not_ meta!  this is tech question on how to provide a UI feature similar to one in SO

Comment: Not meta. This is clearly a programming question about how to program something the OP *happened* to see on Stack Overflow; *not* a meta question about Stack Overflow. The WMD editor was originally a 3rd-party application, anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They use an HTML editor called [WMD Markdown Editor.](http://wmd-editor.com/)

Comment: Off the top of my head no, as I've never used it. But taking a look at the features section of their website, they say to look at optionsExample.html in the zip folder for configuration help.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    // whenever the text in the editor box changes:
    $("#editorTextArea").change(function(){
        // add the text to the preview box below
        // this certainly involves some formatting/marking up of the text
        // but this is good enough for illustrative purposes
        $("#previewBox").val(this.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work like that because the change Event is only fired after the blur event; or: change will only fire if the content has changed AFTER it lost its focus. If you want to update while typing, you pretty much have to go with the keydown Event.